# Using a dynamically sized set of rows with inputs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My data model is something like the following

```
records
└─ record
   └─ id: 0
   └─ name: "Foo"
   └─ property: true
└─ record
   └─ id: 1
   └─ name: "Bar"
   └─ property: false
└─ record
   └─ id: 2
   └─ name: "Baz"
   └─ property: true
```

And I want to create a user interface to it using something like the following:

```html
<div class="row">
  <input type="hidden" value="0"></input>
  <input type="text" value="Foo"></input>
  <input type="checkbox" checked></input>
  <button>Remove</button>
</div>
...
```

I am using angular for my project, and the code snippet I have is

```html
<div ng-controller="ThingsController">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="thing in things" ng-controller="ThingController">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="id"></input>
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="property"></input>
    <button ng-click="remove()">Remove</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

with the following controllers:

```js
angular.module('mymodule', [])
.controller('ThingsController', function($scope) {

  $scope.things = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "Foo"
    property: true
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "Bar"
    property: false
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "Baz"
    property: true
  }];

  $scope.remove = function(idx) {
    $scope.things.splice(idx, 1);
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    $scope.things.push({
      id: $scope.things.length,
      name: 'Placeholder',
      property: true
    });
  };
})

.controller('ThingController', function($scope) {

  $scope.remove = function() {
    $scope.$parent.remove($scope.$index);
  };
});
```

This code doesn't work - a new set of input fields are created when we push to ng-repeat, but the models are not connected up correctly. When I inspect the situation, I see that there are actually 2 scopes, one for the `ng-repeat` and within this another for the `ng-controller`.

My question is: what am I doing wrong? Do I need to not use a new controller? Does anyone use this pattern to create variable length forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing the object inside the `ng-repeat`, you have to use like `thing.id`, `think.name`, `think.property` and so on.

```
<div ng-controller="ThingsController">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="thing.id"></input>
    <input type="text" ng-model="thing.name"></input>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="thing.property"></input>
    <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and place your `remove` function inside your ThingsController

```
$scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.things.splice(index, 1);
};
```

You really do not need `ThingController`.

Comment: This is it. I did read the documentation on ng-repeat, but just didn't spot how it linked to my case. Thanks for the quick response!